# How to select all elements that ends with certain id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: let me reformulate this question

How to select all elements that ends with certain id

**Ex:**

```
<input id="person">
<span id="span_person"></span>
<input id="person_001">
```

My problem is, when I select with jQuery like

```
$("[id*=person]");
```

all inputs with similar id's are returning but in this case I just want to select the first two. I want to select all elements that the id ends with "person". Is there any way?

I use a framework that generates html code, so I can't change the id of the elements because it's based on the attribute name on the framework.

Comment: You can't use the same ID more than once.

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('#person')`. But it is not advisable to use same id for different html element on same page, it might produce unexpected result.

Comment: Firstly that NOT how you close the input element use this to `/>` Secondly, Consider using class or change your ID's to be unique. It NOT a good and very bad idea in coding to use same id's for different elements.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just an example. I don't have two elements with the exact same id, but I have elements that the id contains the same name, like in the example. My question is, I only want to select the element with id "person" but the element with id "person_001" is returning too.

Comment: use just `$("#person")`

Answer (score 0):

Use the $ operand for CSS selectors

```
[attribute$=value]  

$("[id$='person']");

eg. Selects every element whose attribute value ends with value
```

Comment: Thanks. that's exactly what I needed

Comment: Just in case you need more of them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors. Attribute selectors on the bottom left is what you're looking for

Answer (score -1):

An id is supposed to be unique.  You should use a class to group elements you want to style with similar CSS, something like '.person'.  Refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Comment: i'm not using the same id, I reformulated the question

Answer (score -1):

ID is only! You can't set ID for 2 tags!

> 

I should change your span's id!

Comment: i'm not using the same id, I reformulated the question